# How to write a value of email dynamically to json file?

Tags: javascript, json

My Json file looks like this:

**test.json:**

```
{
    "email": "kris@mailinator.com",
    "password": "Sanju@143",
    "fName": "naresh",
    "lName": "surya",
    "MName": "kumar",
}
```

So my scenario is I want to make that email value as dynamic(*___@mailinator.com*). The gap will be filled dynamically. I'll be using this json in my protractor automation later.

Comment: _"You can not write file using `client-side` JavaScript"_

Comment: Run a for loop and fill the email value everytime and push this string into an array

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

initial object :

```
var jsonObj = {
    "password": "Sanju@143",
    "fName": "naresh",
    "lName": "surya",
    "MName": "kumar",
}
```

Now, you have to add `email` property in this object dynamically.

```
jsonObj.email = value;
```

Here, `value` is an email address.Run a for loop and fill this email property value dynamically in the `jsonObj`.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add mail domain with user so every user your email domain if fixed i thought so if it fixed then do it like this.

```
var emailDomain = '@mailinator.com';
var jsonObj = {
    "password": "Sanju@143",
    "fName": "naresh",
    "lName": "surya",
    "MName": "kumar",
}
jsonObj.email = (value+emailDomain );
```

where value : It input by the user in input box